# OpenCV blob detection not discriminating between well defined blobs

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to detect well-defined blobs in some images, I can easily threshold the image to have just the white spots I want to detect but the blob detector seems to group some of them together or miss others. Is there a better way to do this? Is there some way to find every island of connected white pixels that is not super slow?

Thresholded image:

[image: Thresholded image]

Detected Blobs:

[image: Detected Blobs]

The code used to process the Threshold into blobs:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
# we are looking for white blobs in a mask
params.blobColor = 255
params.filterByColor = True
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 0
# Blobs larger than 50 pixels are noise
params.maxArea = 50
# enabling these can cause us to miss points
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.filterByInertia = False
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

img = cv2.imread('Threshold Out.png', flags=cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

keypoints = detector.detect(img)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
img = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                        cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

while True:
    cv2.imshow('out', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: To debug it, I would try thresholding again, or counting the colours, after `cvtColor()` to be sure that all pixels really are 0 or 255.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You'll notice that I apply the detector before converting it to RGB in order to avoid those kinds of issues

Comment: Ooops, yes. Maybe check a line earlier then in case the reading has done you in.

Comment: I actually encountered the problem you described, before that's how I found out about the cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE flag

Comment: I don't speak Python, but should it say `flags=` in the `imread`?

Comment: Yep see the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) for imread() flags is a [Keyword Argument](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

Comment: Try inverting the image and looking for black blobs... http://stackoverflow.com/a/42586912/2836621

Comment: I had some problems while using SimpleBlobDetector in C++ (It may be same for python also). For better solution, you can write your own blob detection algorithm by using canny edge detection and findcontours methods.

Comment: Just FYI, there are exactly 51 blobs and none of them exceed 50 pixels in area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading through the [C docs for the blob detector params](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector) there is a parameter called `minDistBetweenBlobs` and setting this to 1 solved my issue.

Detected Blobs:

[image]

Updated code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
# we are looking for white blobs in a mask
params.blobColor = 255
params.filterByColor = True
params.filterByArea = True
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 1
params.minArea = 0
# Blobs larger than 50 pixels are noise
params.maxArea = 50
# enabling these can cause us to miss points
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.filterByInertia = False
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

img = cv2.imread('Threshold Out.png', flags=cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

keypoints = detector.detect(img)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
img = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                        cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

while True:
    cv2.imshow('out', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Well done and thank you for sharing back with the community.